# Passing pointer to a stack allocated array to function

Tags: c, function, stack, parameter-passing, allocation

I have a function with the prototype below, the 3rd parameter (output variable) is the only relevant:

```
int ioman_write_pages(void**, unsigned, HDD_address**, /*rest is irrelevant*/)
```

The HDD_address type in case someone asks:

```
typedef union { 
    unsigned long long address;

    struct {
      unsigned long long offset : 12;
      unsigned long long page_number : 26;
      unsigned long long : 0;
    } paddress;
} HDD_address;
```

**Call scenario with heap allocation** (Working perfectly):

```
HDD_address* page = (HDD_address*)malloc( pagecount * sizeof(HDD_address) );
memset( page, 0, pagecount * sizeof(HDD_address) );

ioman_write_pages( data, 3, &page, block, NULL, NULL );

printf( "Pages written to: [%d, %d, %d]\n", 
        page[0].address >> 9, 
        page[1].address >> 9, 
        page[2].address >> 9 );
```

Output (Expected: 0, 16, 24):

```
Pages written to: [0, 16, 24]
```

The above heap allocation works no problem.

**If however I attempt a stack allocation of "page":**

```
HDD_address page[pagecount];
memset( page, 0, pagecount * sizeof(HDD_address) );

ioman_write_pages( data, 3, &page, block, NULL, NULL );
```

Output, while data wise nonsensical, it is consistent:

```
Pages written to: [166956, 0, 0]
```

Compile warning when compiling the above:

```
note: expected ‘union HDD_address **’ but argument is of type ‘union HDD_address (*)[(sizetype)(pagecount)]’
```

**Stack allocation, "fixing" the warning:**

```
DD_address page[pagecount];
memset( page, 0, pagecount * sizeof(HDD_address) ); 
HDD_address* ppage = page; 

int r = ioman_write_pages( data, 3, &ppage, block, NULL, NULL );
```

Output, again consistent every run but nonsense:

```
Pages written to: [1610376, 2856870, 610607]
```

I cannot make any sense of this at all, someone please enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to pass it a double pointer, chances are the function does the allocation itself (and changes the pointed pointer).

Comment: It's my own function, the caller is (supposedly) responsible for allocation the 3rd parameter.
It was however not the case, it did in fact reallocate.. Fixing it solved it.